# how not to consider @NotBlank in some methods

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I'm doing a restful app in Spring boot,jpa,mysql. I have annoted some of my model fields @NotBlank to print an error in the creation of an object if those fields are blank.
Now when i'm updating, I don't want to get that error if I don't set some fields in my json body.My goal is to update just the fields which are present.
So I want to know if there is a way not to consider an @NotBlank in my updating method.

This is the code source :

For the Entity

```
public class Note implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank(name)
private String title;

@NotBlank
private String content;
//Getters and Setters

}
```

The controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class NoteController {

@Autowired
NoteRepository noteRepository;

// Create a new Note
@PostMapping("/notes")
public Note createNote(@Valid @RequestBody Note note) {
    return noteRepository.save(note);
}

// Update a Note

@PutMapping("/notes/{id}")
public Note partialUpdateNote(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long noteId,
                                         @RequestBody Note noteDetails) {          
    Note note = noteRepository.findById(noteId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Note", "id",   noteId));
    //copyNonNullProperties(noteDetails, note);

    if(note.getTitle()!= null) {
        note.setTitle(noteDetails.getTitle());
    }else {
        note.setTitle(note.getTitle());
    }

    if(note.getContent()!= null) {
        note.setContent(noteDetails.getContent());
    }else {
        note.setContent(note.getContent());
    }
    Note updatedNote = noteRepository.save(note);
    return updatedNote;
}

// Delete a Note
@DeleteMapping("/notes/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteNote(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long noteId) {
    Note note = noteRepository.findById(noteId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Note", "id", noteId));

    noteRepository.delete(note);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
}
```

ResourceNotFoundException is the class responsible to throws errors.

Comment: Omitting `@Valid` should work just fine. Is there something wrong with your current code?

Comment: I omitted it voluntarily to understand how it works, because I was able to solve the same problem with an application in memory and it worked very well, the problem was on noteRepository.findById(noteId) that I could not cast in Note

Answer (score 1):

You can use groups for that.

Add two interfaces `CreateGroup` and `UpdateGroup`.

Use them by this way:

```
@NotBlank(groups = CreateGroup.class)
@Null(groups = UpdateGroup.class)
private String title;
```

In the create endpoint

`@Valid @ConvertGroup(from = Default.class, to = CreateGroup.class) Note note`

In the update endpoint

`@Valid @ConvertGroup(from = Default.class, to = UpdateGroup.class) Note note`

Probably you don't need `UpdateGroup`. It is just to show a common approach.
Also for the nested objects inside `Note` something like

`@ConvertGroup(from = CreateGroup.class, to = UpdateGroup.class)`

can be used.

Comment: The answer points in the right direction, but I think you should mention that converting from the `Default` group will also suppress any validation constraints for which no groups have been explicitly declared

Comment: @vladynev and I'm still pretty sure [I'm right](https://github.com/crizzis/validation-test)